# What exactly is a property?

Tags: soft-question, philosophy, meta-math

How is a property $P$ formally defined in mathematics?

I mean for example if $f$ is a morphism from an object $X$ to $Y$ in some category, then somehow I feel that "has codomain $Y$" is too broad to be considered a property...

Comment: So what's narrow enough to be a property for you?

Comment: Whatever the case, maybe this will be useful to you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(philosophy)#Properties_in_mathematics

Comment: Why is that too broad? Is "has two arms" too broad to be a property of people?

Comment: I was thinking a property should be something that is independent of the category axioms, like does not make referene to domain codomain, "is a morphism" "is an object" etc.. but this is difficult to express clearly in mathematics

Comment: I tend to think it's better in mathematics to think of "has a property" as "satisfies a formula". Generally, the status of "properties", "attributes", or "propositions", where these aren't formulas or sentences, is a rather involved philosophical issue.

Comment: Hmm, well in my personal experience, a formal mathematical definition of "property" has never been necessary, nor do I think one would have been useful. The natural language meaning has always been enough. I bet logicians have a formal definition, though: good for them!

Answer (score 3):

The [wiki says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_%28philosophy%29):

> In mathematical terminology, a property p defined for all elements of a set X is usually defined as a function p: X → {true, false}, that is true whenever the property holds; or equivalently, as the subset of X for which p holds; i.e. the set {x| p(x) = true}; p is its indicator function.

This is plausible, but strictly speaking one would like to allow X to be a proper class so that one could talk about a property of groups, topologies, etc.

Really, the natural language meaning is enough to do most mathematics.